# vectorized ind2sub in Julia

Tags: julia

Is there vectorized method of `ind2sub()` in Julia?

Here is the example that will clarify and motivate my question:

```
A = rand(3,5)
(vals, inds) = findmax(A, 1)
```

Now I have vector of linear indices `inds`, which I would like to convert to subscripts, or more precisely, to the row index corresponding to maximum value.

Something like

```
ind2sub(A, inds)
```

or

```
map(ind2sub, A, inds)
```

won't do the job...

Feedback: I would like bring dev. team's attention to this.
IMO, this is an example of providing hammer, but not providing nails, speaking metaphorically. That is if users are provided with vectorized `findmax` there should also be vectorized `ind2sub` that will play nicely with it. Though I agree that vectorizing `ind2sub` might be tricky.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Julia 0.5 and onwards, you use broadcasting for vectorised operations:

```
julia v0.5> A = rand(3, 5);

julia v0.5> (vals, inds) = findmax(A, 1);

julia v0.5> ind2sub.([A], inds)
1×5 Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},2}:
 (1,1)  (1,2)  (3,3)  (2,4)  (3,5)
```

See this recent blog post:
http://julialang.org/blog/2017/01/moredots

Comment: This should be updated for newer versions of Julia.